# How can I boost production late in the game to get a Science victory?

Tags: civilization-6

I've found that leading in science at King level isn't too hard in Civ 6, but there's a huge amount of production required in order to complete the 5 Spaceport projects

What can I do to boost my late-game production?

**Edit:** This should be less of an issue since the [Winter 2016 patch reduced the cost of all Space Race projects by 40%](https://steamcommunity.com/games/289070/announcements/detail/599374259662898714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

City:

- Obvious one first: focus your city on production!
- <strike>Aim to build other cities' Industrial Zones within 6 tiles of your main production city's city center, to benefit from their Power Plant bonus</strike>

Note that since the [Winter 2016 patch](https://steamcommunity.com/games/289070/announcements/detail/599374259662898714), factories no longer stack:

> Cities can no longer receive yields from more than one regional
>   building per type; they take the highest (ex. production from multiple
>   Factories)

Wonders:

- Ruhr Valley (+30% production, and +1 Production for each Mine and Quarry in this city.  Must be built along a River adjacent to an Industrial Zone district with a Factory).

Trade:

- Base trade routes from this city, prioritizing production
- Until you get Ecommerce (see below), domestic trade will probably generate more production than international

Great People:

- Sergei Korolev (Great Engineer) grants 1,500 production towards Space Race project construction
- Carl Sagan (Great Scientist) grants 3,000 production towards Space Race project construction - enough to one-shot a Mars component

Builders:

- Chop woods belonging to your production city to grant 200 production (or jungle for 100 production/100 food).  Then replant woods and create Lumber Mills (note that you can't chop rebuilt woods).

  - Chopping woods for production can be done more than 3 tiles from your city, providing the production city is the closest of your cities to the wood.
- Build mines on any unoccupied hills, especially next to the Industrial Zone

  - Remember that mines will still provide an adjacency bonus to your Industrial Zone even if the mine itself is 4 tiles from your city.

Government:

- Consider switching to Communism for the 10% production bonus

Policies:

- Integrated Space Cell (+15% production towards Space Race Projects if a city has either a Military Academy or a Seaport).
- Ecommerce (+5 production and +10 gold from international Trade Routes)
- Arsenal of Democracy (Your Trade Routes to an Ally's city provide +2 Food and +2 Production for both cities)
- Five-Year Plan (+100% Campus and Industrial Zone district adjacency bonuses)

City States:

- Prioritize getting suzerainty of Industrial cities

Comment: To add to the great people: Sergei Korolev (Great Engineer) also grants production to a space race project.

Comment: To also add to the great people, Robert Goddard adds another +20% hammers towards space race projects.